# OAuth 2.0 Header In Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to make a GET request with axios. How do I implement an OAuth 2.0 header to axios? I'm able to get this to work in Postman (see below), but not in axios.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding an header with `Authentication: Bearer {token}` to your axios request.

Like so:

```
      axios.get(url, {  
                 headers : { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+YOUR_TOKEN_HERE }
            })

       .then((response) => console.log(response))
```